# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: vue.js, vite

This is my first time to deploy vue/vite application, i get server from digital ocean and install apache2 then install my application but when i hit the route of the application i got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

here is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

const path = require('path');

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets')
    }
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 4000, 
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
})
```

also i have to mention when i run npm run dev on the server and open it via server port it worl perfect but i only get error when i hit the server ip

Comment: Hi, did you resolve the issue? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add into defineConfig

```
base: '/'
```

Also i personali just import path instead of require

```
import path from 'path';
```

After all you could also try npm run build to check production setup from time to time build sees more error's then dev cause it's more strict in development mode is allows some bugs just to go

Comment: the main problem here that vite can't read vue and it's imported right and as a proof for that when i run npm dev on server and hit server-ip:port it work fine but when i hit server-ip it should redirect users to the folder of the project where i creaded this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [NC,L]
```

this htaccess to redirect it to index.html in the root where it contain main.js

Comment: Are you using laravel? if yes on server you should set base directory as /public

Comment: Or maybe you should just let it use automatic port instead of set 4000?
Also you could check if server allow mod_rewrite, Else maybe if this dont hit index you could also try add "DirectoryIndex index.php" into htaccess (i bet ur using php)